# Equation in PostgreSQL only returns 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i have these query to get the percentage of downtime that occurred that is below 95 but the problem this query only returns 0 which is i don't get why since the data that i'm putting has values.
Please see query below:

```
SELECT ROUND(
    (
        (SELECT COUNT(*) AS terminal_down_count FROM dashboard.availability WHERE availability_percentage < 95 AND availability_date = '2020-04-05'
        ) / t.terminal_count
    ) * 100, 9)
FROM(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS terminal_count
FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date = '2020-04-05'
)t
```

If I highlight the query `SELECT COUNT(*) AS terminal_down_count FROM dashboard.availability WHERE availability_percentage < 95 AND availability_date = '2020-04-05'`
This is what it will return:

[image]

While if I highlight this query `SELECT COUNT(*) AS terminal_count FROM dashboard.availability WHERE availability_date = '2020-04-05` It will return this result:

[image]

So basically what i'm trying to return in the equation is something like this:

```
(146 / 4,272) * 100 = 3.42
```

But the overall query above it only outputs 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following, convert `terminal_down_count` to float. so multiply with `1.0` as shown below or do cast to float. Here is the [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7LnbfpwvGoKrFebY75xNBf/1).

```
SELECT ROUND(
    (
        (SELECT 
          COUNT(*) AS terminal_down_count 
          FROM dashboard.availability 
          WHERE availability_percentage < 95 
          AND availability_date = '2020-04-05'
        )*1.0 / t.terminal_count
    ) * 100, 9)
FROM(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS terminal_count
FROM dashboard.availability
WHERE availability_date = '2020-04-05'
)t
```